# Validate file path parameter

Tags: powershell

```
param ([ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf })][string]$filePath)
```

If I declare a parameter like this, will `$filePath` evaluate to false if it's an invalid path?

Is the point of this to do something like

```
if($filePath) { /* do stuff... */ }
```

or will an exception be thrown?

Comment: An exception will be thrown

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the `ValidateScript` attribute if your function requires a valid path. PowerShell will throw the error for you if the user provides an invalid path. You probably also want to add `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` otherwise you can omit the `$filePath`parameter and the function will get called without an exception.

Here is an example:

```
function This-IsYourFunction 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string]
        $filePath
    )

    Write-Host "Hello, World."
}
```

Comment: This is really great!! The param block for all my scripts is gonna contain half my code now (jk but no really--rip my successor). And you know I'm gonna comment it, especially so that I can have every type of bracket right next to each other (ie. `[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ <# Saves some time for later #>})]`